# How do you find the limit of $x^2/(1-\cos^2x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$?

Tags: calculus

edit:
This question is be votting off-topic for missing context or detail, so here is the context.
It's a part of the problem set after the first lecture of a single varieble calculus course. I spent literally 3+ hours on it, and I could not solving it. So please help!

Comment: Noting $1-\cos(x)^2=\sin(x)^2$ it should be pretty clear it approaches $1$. Or use l'hospital's rule three times lol

Comment: You may also calculate the Taylor series expansion of $\cos^2(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's a part of the problem set after the first lecture of a single varieble calculus course. It seems l'hospital's rule and Talor series would be future parts of the course. Now I recall that $cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)=1$, and it's not a problem anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly seems to be the problem? Do you recall the good old limit $\lim_\limits{\theta \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$?

$$
\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos^2x}=
\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}=
\left[\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{x}{\sin x}\right]^2=
\left[\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\cdot \frac{1/x}{1/x}\right)\right]^2=\\
\left[\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\right]^2=
\left[\frac{\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0} 1}{\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}}\right]^2=\left(\frac{1}{1}\right)^2=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the definition of the derivative

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{1-\cos^2x}=-\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2-0^2}{x-0}\dfrac{x-0}{\cos^2x-\cos ^20}=-\lim_{x\to 0}\left[2x\cdot \dfrac{1}{-2\cos x\sin x}\right]=1
$$

You can also use Bernoulli's limit law (aka l'Hospitals rule) to obtain:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{2x}{-2\cos x (-\sin x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{\cos x}}_{\to 1}\underbrace{\dfrac{x}{\sin x}}_{\to 1}=1.$$